# PHP - how to find the meta information of an internal/built-in method programmatically?

Tags: php

Is it possible to find the data about a built in method in PHP via code?

For example, we have array_key_exists() which is an internal method.

I want to find out the parameters in this function programatically. The reason is, there is an up coming interview, and I will have to write code on Notepad. There will not be any internet connection to see PHP documentation.

If I can get the information about built in methods via code, it will be really helpful.

Is it at all possible to print meta data of a function? I am not asking about user defined functions, but about PHP's built in functions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use this `$refFunc = new ReflectionFunction('preg_replace');` if Reflections is installed, but it sounds like cheating what you want to do ;-)  http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Comment: `Notepad` Tip: If you have to use Notepad, i thing you dont can run scripts while interview ;) so no way to get information about functions....

Comment: Absolutely this is what I was searching for. Thanks a lot brother. Yeah, it is some kind of hacking or cheating :D ... It is a practical test. So they will ask me to write a program to do some x task. I will update you here later on.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Reflection i think:

```
$refFunc = new ReflectionFunction('preg_replace');
foreach( $refFunc->getParameters() as $param ){
    print $param;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/class.reflectionfunction.php

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works.  Is there any way to get the list of all PHP's  built in methods or functions  programatically?

Comment: Is there a difference between function and method in PHP? I was a bit confused because I see people using both the terms often.

Comment: Function to get all defined functions:  get_defined_functions()


For your second question look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

(Please upvote if my answer was usefull)

Comment: Thank you so much mr.void  , excellent. I am so happy now, because if at all if I get stuck during the practical test, I can quickly use get_defined_functions() in combination with  ReflectionFunction ... really cool thing.